# Replacing just the match of regular expression in Eclipse find and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

So I have a ton of files that need to be changed. Something like this

```
String example=/abc/def/PATTERN/ghi
```

and I want to change that PATTERN to something else, let's say FIX

What I would like to get is:

```
String example=/abc/def/FIX/ghi
```

What I'm getting is:

FIX (The whole line gets changed, only want the match to be changed)

This is the regular expression I'm using, trying to avoid commented lines

```
^(?!\s*(//|\*)).*/PATTERN/
```

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you were going for... I'll re-read and re-attempt to answer.  I have deleted my initial answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify?  Are you saying that you want to replace the 3rd '/'-delimited piece of the string?  Or are you saying that you want to replace any '/'-delimited piece that matches `PATTERN`?

Comment: I want to replace every /PATTERN/ I see, replacing both / and the pattern word

Comment: So if you have multiple occurrences on the same line (or worse, adjacent occurrences) of /PATTERN/, they should all be replaced?  Also, do you want to replace both the leading *and preceding* occurrences of '/'?

Comment: It will only have one occurrence, so just one would be okay. About the '/', I'm thinking I could just leave them there. Specifically, what I want to do is something like this:

String example=/abc/def/PATTERN/ghi

And I want to replace the pattern with an object field, so instead of PATTERN something like "+Object.getValue()+"

Comment: And will it always be piece 3?  In other words, do you want to replace occurrences like `/abc/PATTERN`?

Comment: Not always, I just need to remove the PATTERN, it does not matter what piece it is

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the part of the pattern you need to keep after replacement into capturing parentheses and use a backreference to it in the replacement string:

*Search for*: `^(?!\s*(?://|\*))(.*/)PATTERN/`
*Replace*:    `$1FIX/`

Now, the pattern matches:

- `^` - start of line
- `(?!\s*(?://|\*))`  - if not followed with 0+ whitespaces and `//` or `*` (note that the non-capturing grop `(?:...)` is used to simplify backreference usage)
- `(.*/)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols up to the last `/`
- `PATTERN/` - a literal substring `PATTERN/`.

In the replacement pattern, `$1` re-inserts the whole line from its start to `/` before the `PATTERN/`, and `FIX/` is the literal replacement part.

[image]